# Vue JS setting data collection in component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js, vue-component

I want to make my code shorter. I have chart js which is using `datacollection` to set options for the chart. I want to render it in another component at use it on my pages.

I want to be able to set det data collection from the component render, based on which chart I want.

I have something like this in my component:

```
<template>
   <div>
     <chart :datacollection="this_will_i_define_on_the_page_i_render_this_component"> </chart>
   </div>
<template>

<script> 
  export {
    name: 'this-chart',
    data () { 
      return {
       DC1: []
       DC2: []
      }
    }
 }
 (basic vue component)
</script>


<template>
  <this-chart :datacollection="DC1"> </this-chart>
  <this-chart :datacollection="DC2"> </this-chart>
</template>
```

So I want to be able to go down in my component and set the `datacollection`. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then based on your comment you could to something like this. Probably more elegant way but should work.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <chart :data-collection="myChartData"></chart>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "this-chart",
  props: {
    activeDataSet: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      validator: value => ["a", "b", "c"].indexOf(value) > -1
    }
  },
  computed: {
    myChartData() {
      const example1 = [{ x: 1, y: 2 }, { x: 2, y: 3 },{ x: 3 y: 4 }];
      const example2 = [{ x: 1, y: 2 }, { x: 2, y: 3 },{ x: 3 y: 4 }];
      const example3 = [{ x: 1, y: 2 }, { x: 2, y: 3 },{ x: 3 y: 4 }];
      if(this.activeDataSet === 'a') return example1
      if(this.activeDataSet === 'b') return example2
      if(this.activeDataSet === 'c') return example3
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

and then to use

```
<template>
    <this-chart activeDataSet="a"></this-chart>
</template>
```

Comment: Okay (Y) ill try this, looks like the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [component props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html).

```
<template>
    <div>
        <chart :data-collection="myChartData"></chart>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "this-chart",
  props: {
    myChartData: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

And to use it

```
<template>
    <this-chart :my-chart-data="exampleData"></this-chart>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "example-component",
  data() {
    return {
      exampleData: [{ x: 5, y: 10 }, { x: 6, y: 11 }]
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Please format your code better next time.

Comment: yes but its a prop from my chart.js i need to set from the place i render my component. Its called :chart-data when i  used it in plane html. and then i render it somewhere in another component so i want to set my charts datacollection from there. do you think props will work with that?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Herteby/pt36djg1/ heres is an example how the component looks inside. as you can see I fill the data collection on the component page. and then i have more than 1 so when i render it my other component as an component i want to set the :chart-data="" from my other component, if it make sense? :)

Comment: If you want to render your component `this-chart` from anywhere else, and dynamically give it different data in each instance, then props are your way to go. In my example, checkout the `this-chart` component and the `props` property it has.

Comment: okay, it's a bit hard to explain :). 

I have my component with the chart. it has 3 datacollections with data and properties in this component.

Then I render this component in the other component.  and from here do I want to define which datacollection it should use.